# In this code how to stop after found or not found string using python

Tags: python

```
import win32com.client
objSWbemServices = win32com.client.Dispatch(
    "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator").ConnectServer(".","root\cimv2")
for item in objSWbemServices.ExecQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity "):
    found=False
    for name in ('Caption','Capabilities '):
        a = getattr(item, name, None)
        if a is not None:
            b=('%s,' %a)
            if "Item" in b:
                print "found"
                found = True

            else:
                print "Not found"
                break
```

I want only One time to display "found" else "not found"

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use a function and substitute return where you have print.  You can exploit the fact that a function in python stops executing when it hits a return.

```
def finder():
    objSWbemServices = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator").ConnectServer(".","root\cimv2")
    for item in objSWbemServices.ExecQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity "):
        for name in ('Caption','Capabilities '):
            a = getattr(item, name, None)
            if a is not None:
                b=('%s,' %a)
                if "Item" in b:
                    return True # or return "Found" if you prefer
                else:
                    return False # or return "Not Found" if you prefer

found = finder()
print found
# or
print finder()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "break" after "if" case like this:

```
for name in ('Caption','Capabilities '):
    a = getattr(item, name, None)
    if a is not None:
        b=('%s,' %a)
        if "Item" in b:
            print "found"
            found = True

            #added here
            break

        else:
            print "Not found"
            break
```

this will break out of iteration over "('Caption','Capabilities ')"

Answer (score 0):

Move `break` one indentation level up:

```
for name in ('Caption','Capabilities '):
    a = getattr(item, name, None)
    if a is not None:
        b=('%s,' %a)
        if "Item" in b:
            print "found"
            found = True
        else:
            print "Not found"

        break
```

Comment: Actually I dont want to print "Not found" multiple times only once I have print

Answer (score 0):

Display? you mean execute, i think.
Just put the break outside the else statement (inside - if a is not None -). in this way, if a is not none the loop is stopped whenever "Item" is in b or not.

```
for name in ('Caption','Capabilities '):
    a = getattr(item, name, None)
    if a is not None:
        b=('%s,' %a)
        if "Item" in b:
            print "found"
            found = True

        else:
            print "Not found"
        break
```

EDIT: See warwaruk anser

Comment: Actually I dont want to print "Not found" not multiple times only one time I have to print

Comment: This code print "found" or "Not found" (depending on 'if "Item" in b:') just one time.

Comment: If Item is not found the sould How to stop the loop

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand what you have written.

Comment: Ok, If item is not found then should not loop in to it print "not found" one time on a screen

Comment: Ok, so just remove the else statement.

Comment: suppose I removed else part if item is not found then "not found" is not showing